# RollingFileAppender that also deletes files older than some date

Tags: java, log4j, logback

Do any of the popular Java logging frameworks support a rolling file appender, that I can configure to rollover daily, and also delete any log file that is over some number of days old? I know I could use a rolling file appender and a cron, but was wondering if anyone knew of an appender that can do both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logback's classic RollingFileAppender provides this and more. An example configuration from the manual (http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#onRollingPolicies)

```
 <configuration>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

      <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender> 

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

This provides daily rollover and 30 days of history. Place this in a file called logback.xml, or logback-test.xml for test trees, and place it in the classpath.

Comment: Looks promising, trying it out. I didn't know maxHistory worked with a time based rolling policy.

Comment: There are other reasons to adopt logback over log4j. Here are some:

 - Its has a good relationship to slf4j so that other logging apis can be directed to a single logger. This removes any ambiguity from logging configuration.
 - Configuration is easily understood and doesn't suffer from bootstrapping issues.
 - Its feature rich and easy to get information about the logging initialisation/errors.

Comment: Also mentioned in the docs: http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html#maxHistory

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if you are using Log4J you can use this appender:

- http://blog.kimb3r.com/2008/07/improving-log4j-dailyrollingfileappende.html

It's very, very, VERY easy to use, just download the whole class(*yes, the code of the class in the above link*), include it in your project (*wherever you want, you can change the package to match inside your project*), and then configure the log4j.properties file like this(*this file has to be in your classpath, for example in the src/main/resources folder*):

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = log
log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, FILE

# Define the logical path where you put the class you downloaded from "blog.kimb3r.com" link (above)
log4j.appender.FILE=com.yourapp.yourpackage.log.CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/yourlogfile.log
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
# How many files you want to keep?, in this case I'm having just 15 days of files, one file per day:
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxNumberOfDays=15
# If True, the older files will be compressed into a zip file (*which will save you a lot of space on the server*)
log4j.appender.FILE.CompressBackups=true
```

and besides this just add the dependency to log4j into your pom like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

After working a while on Log4j, I read that Logback was developed and designed to be the successor of [Log4j](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html), and I have to say, Logback is wide stepper!

For example, to configure, this rolling file Appender, and zip the older logs, and have a maximum of 30, on Log4J you have to perform some code changes (please review my previews [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931658/rollingfileappender-that-also-deletes-files-older-than-some-date/29971298#29971298) for more details), but on logback, everything is done on the config file like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>log/logFile.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>log/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>

            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%-5level]: [%logger{35}] - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

And that's it, you will have the current log unzipped, and the older days, zip, one zip file by each day.

Wide more easier than log4j!

If you want to play with more config options, just check [this link](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why not  look at [this](http://developerselixir.blogspot.in/2008/07/improving-log4j-dailyrollingfileappende.html) might help?

You can probably set maximum nuber of days to retain the logs.

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE
>   log4j.appender.FILE=ca.justtechnologies.utils.logging.CustodianDailyRollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MMM dd yyyy
>   HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %l - %m%n
>   log4j.appender.FILE.File=/var/log/web-apps/Dashboard.log
>   log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
>
> **log4j.appender.FILE.MaxNumberOfDays=14**
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.CompressBackups=true

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look, was hoping to not have to compile anything (but can if I have to if there's nothing built in to an existing lib).

Comment: @AlperAkture: that shouldn't take so much effort! :)

Comment: Totally agree, it's the testing part, and then the risks of pushing new code out to a bunch of servers. But I haven't ruled it out yet!